# Function that finds last row in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a simple function that has 1 cell input based on which, it offsets the last consecutively filled cell in this roll.

```
Option Explicit
Function LastCell(CellA As String)

    LastCell = Range(CellA).End(xlDown).Value

End Function
```

For some reason, it is not work...

Without VBA, I achieve the desired result through: `=LOOKUP(9E+50,B:B)` for example.

Not a very elegant and not always useful.

Comment: How are you calling the function? What do you pass inside LastCell?

Comment: Let's say I have a column from `A1:A400` filled with dates. I wish to be able to get the value in cell `A400` by inputting the value in cell `A1`, so my formula should look like this: `LastCell(A1)` should equal to the value in cell `A400`

Comment: You are going to need to put quotes around A1. So it should be LastCell("A1").

Comment: @rwilson it did work with my code and your input about putting the quotes. How can I get rid of them though?

Comment: I don't know if you can. If you don't have the quotes "Option Explicit" sees it as a variable not defined.

Comment: I see, well I will keep searching for a way, as it does make a big difference. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Option Explicit
Function LastCell(CellA As range)
    LastCell = CellA.End(xlDown).Value
End Function
```

use it as =LastCell(B1)

Note that this method does not work well with hidden or filtered rows or merged cells.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your lookup is fine with numbers but will return `#N/A` if the column contains only text or possibly the wrong answer if mixed text and numbers. A more definitive formula might be,

```
=max(iferror(match(1e99, B:B), 0), iferror(match("žžž", B:B), 0))
```

That will identify the row with the last number, date or text value. Errors are ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the input Jeepad, however I am looking for a VBA solution, as I wish to add some filters once I have the basic in place.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the function try:

```
MsgBox LastCell(ActiveCell.Address)
```

In the example you gave, you need to call the function like this:

```
LastCell("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, Come from the bottom up rather than the top down:

```
LastCell = cells(rows.count,CellA.column).End(xlUp).Value
```

This returns the value of the last cell (Similar to your code), if you want the address then change .Value to .Address.

Edit: Also change the dim of CellA from String to Range

Comment: This looks like you understand what I am trying to do, however it gives me a Compile error: Invalid qualifier

Comment: It's just the way your calling it.

Comment: In the sheet enter =LastCell("A1") or in VBA code use MsgBox LastCell(Range("A1"))